# How to provide ArrayList<Uri> content for Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app where you can select multiple images. This app also will appear in the chooser dialog for attachments of images from different clients like Gmail, Message app, WhatsApp etc.
When i open WhatsApp and i press attach photo, i will choose my app, select multiple images and i will set them to be returned to WhatsApp. How to send multiple images to client?
Here is what i wrote:

```
 ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
 for (int i = 0; i < tempFile.size(); i++)
  { File fileIn = tempFile.get(i);
    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
    uris.add(u);
  }
  if (tempFile != null) {
  Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);    
  data.setType("image/png");
  data.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
  MainActivity.getInstance().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,data);
  getActivity().finish();
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
This is a post that opens a chooser.. I dont need a chooser...you just tap multiple files in my application...press ok..and that s it...you are returned to Whats App where you pressed attach image button...you know already where you should put the files...dont need a chooser anymore.

Comment: `if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action))
            && Intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
        // retrieve a collection of selected images
        ArrayList<Parcelable> list = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    // iterate over these images
    for (Parcelable parcel : list) {
       Uri uri = (Uri) parcel;
       // handle the images one by one here
   }
}`



SO i am not the receiver...to handle the response...i send the images to WhatsApp or gmail or Message app..this dont need to be implemented on my side. i need to setResult() somehow.